# How to integrate a chat bot with a pre-trained question answering model?

Tags: python, chatbot, nlp-question-answering, haystack

**Introduction**

I have recently worked on building a question answering model using [Haystack](https://haystack.deepset.ai/). The model takes as input, a question and returns an answer based on the closed domain data, which in my case is, Information about Machine Learning.
I want to integrate this model into a chatbot and add it to my website.

**Problem**

The problem that I am facing is that I cannot find any tools or resources that would help me do this. Most of them use intents and entities etc, while I want to focus on a more simple solution of just question answering.

*Are there any tools that build a chatbot for a website and allow integration of my model for responding to the user input?*

**Additional Information**

My model is written in Python. Right now I have deployed on a sample web app using flask and I get inputs using a form.

Answer (score 2):

the standard approach to this would be to set up a Haystack QA system and interact with it via [the REST API](https://github.com/deepset-ai/haystack/blob/master/README.md#7-rest-api).

As for the Chatbot side, Rasa is a popular option. There has been much community interest in getting Haystack integrated with Rasa and I'd recommend you have a scan of [this Github thread](https://github.com/deepset-ai/haystack/issues/809) to see what's been done.

If you'd like some more specific follow up advice, please feel free to join [our Slack channel](https://haystack.deepset.ai/community/join) where we'd be happy to continue the conversation about making Haystack work for your project!